# json array of object is useless (not efficient)

Tags: arrays, json, csv, bson, data-transfer-objects

I use JSON for sending data through an API for clients.
My data is a JSON array of objects, each
object in the array has the same type,
and the keys value are the same for all.
70% of a request is consumed by repeating useless key names.
Is there way to send data without this overhead?

"I know some way exists like csv but **I want to choose general solution** for this problem"

> for example my array in json 5Mb  and in csv its only 500kb

A simple json array

> ```
> var people = [
>   { firstname:"Micro",  hasSocialNetworkSite: false, lastname:"Soft", site:"http://microsoft.com" },
>   { firstname:"Face",   hasSocialNetworkSite: true, lastname:"Book", site:"http://facebook.com" },
>   { firstname:"Go",     hasSocialNetworkSite: true, lastname:"ogle", site:"http://google.com" },
>   { firstname:"Twit",   hasSocialNetworkSite: true, lastname:"Ter", site:"http://twitter.com" },
>   { firstname:"App",    hasSocialNetworkSite: false, lastname:"Le",   site:"http://apple.com" },
> ];
> ```

and this above array in csv format

> ```
> "firstname","hasSocialNetworkSite","lastname","site"
> "Micro","False","Soft","http://microsoft.com"
> "Face","True","Book","http://facebook.com"
> "Go","True","ogle","http://google.com"
> "Twit","True","Ter","http://twitter.com"
> "App","False","Le","http://apple.com"
> ```

you can see that the performance of json array of object in example.

Comment: "you can see that the performance of json array and...." And what?

Comment: This is where using a schema such as JSON API or doing some normalization on the database would be of benefit.

Comment: Send the content in a compressed form.  `gzip` should do a good job on content with that much repetition.  Or use shorter key names. Single-letter key names will work for the example you show.  If the long key names are required at the other end and you don't want to write specific logic at the receiver to map short key names to long key names for each type of message then send a short-to-long-name mapping as part of the request.

Comment: gzip not good solution it's like to be
"That cat shut its eyes while stealing cream"::

Comment: "file size" is not "performance". It's entirely possible that processing the json is much faster. Besides, [compressed streams are part of the standards of http communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression).

Answer (score 0):

Why would using a csv file not be a 'general solution'?

If your data is tabular you don't really need a hierachical format like json or xml.

You can even shrink your csv file further by removing the double quotes (those are only needed when there is a separator inside the field):

```
firstname,hasSocialNetworkSite,lastname,site
Micro,False,Soft,http://microsoft.com
Face,True,Book,http://facebook.com
Go,True,ogle,http://google.com
Twit,True,Ter,http://twitter.com
App,False,Le,http://apple.com
```

Comment: Useing csv ini my server for some response not general,because sometime I sending csv(for arrays) and some time I send json

Comment: The quotes are necessary because should find out the ',' is for Separator or in value, *value can contain each characters

Comment: @aminsaffar That's right, but you only need quotes for the fields that contain a separator. In the example there are none.

Comment: CSV [has a standard](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180), by the way. Fields indeed only require quotes around them if they contain either a line break, a quote or the split character.